# jQuery using each with insertBefore

Tags: jquery

Honestly I don't know how to explain this, but if you see the code and result you know what I'm trying to do. Trying to seperate `spans` from each `'divide'` div.

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>text1<span>subtxt1</span></div>
    <div>text2<span>subtxt2</span></div>
    <div>text3<span>subtxt3</span></div>
    <div>text4<span>subtxt4</span></div>
    <div>text5<span>subtxt5</span></div>
    <div>text6<span>subtxt6</span></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var divs = $(".wrapper div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
  divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='divide'></div>");
}

$('.divide').each(function(){
  $(this).find('span').insertBefore($(this).next());
});
```

here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VB6fj/

Basically last three span didnt moved. I want it separated like first three `span`
Thx

Comment: Honestly I have no clue what you're trying to do based on that description and the Fiddle, but it could just be me ?

Comment: Could you show the HTML you're trying to create with those manipulations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).next()` is empty for the last `.divide` since there are no more siblings. You can replace that line with this:

```
$(this).find('span').insertAfter(this)
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/VB6fj/2/